# Generar .bat para ejecutar consultas SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente serie de consultas:

```
delete from OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT * from clientes2 WHERE IDCliente>2')

insert into OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT IDCliente, Grupo, Codigo,
Denominacion, CUIT, TipoCliente, Responsable1, Activo FROM clientes2')
select IDCliente, Grupo, Codigo, Denominacion, CUIT, TipoCliente,
Responsable1, Activo from SQLSERVERDB.dbo.Clientes WHERE IDCliente > 3
```

Hay forma de generar un archivo para que alguien que no tiene idea de SQL pueda ejecutar estas 2 consultas de manera sensilla sin tener que entrar al management studio?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar tus consultas en un archivo "query.sql" y mandarlo llamar desde un batch con el comando sqlcmd, por ejemplo:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\"
sqlcmd.exe -S DBserverName -U username -P p@ssword -i "C:\query.sql" -s "," | findstr /V /C:"-" /B >"c:\output.csv"
```

[Ejecutar archivos de secuencias de comandos Transact-SQL mediante sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms170572(v=sql.90).aspx)

[La utilidad sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms180944.aspx)

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo corregí. Gracias

Comment: Qué iría en DBServername?

Comment: El nombre de tu servidor e instancia, por ejemplo: SERVER\SQLEXPRESS o simplemente el nombre del servidor si la instancia es anónima:  SERVER

Comment: Ok, y si todos los datos estuvieran en un servidor, y quisiera ejecutar el .bat desde otra pc, cómo debería hacer?

Comment: Prácticamente serían la mismas sentencias, lo único que necesitas es tener un nombre de usuario y contraseña válidos en SQL SERVER, y que tu query .sql esté en la computadora donde deseas ejecutarlo o bien en una carpeta compartida.

Comment: Muchas Gracias lo hice y salio perfecto

Comment: Me alegro, por favor dale clic en ^ a la respuesta para que sirva a otros. Gracias